# Error in substituting '(' with regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, substitution, parentheses

Hi have the following string:

```
s = r'aaa (bbb (ccc)) ddd'
```

and I would like to find and replace the innermost nested parentheses with `{}`. Wanted output:

```
s = r'aaa (bbb {ccc}) ddd'
```

Let's start with the nested `(`. I use the following regex in order to find nested parentheses, which works pretty good:

```
match = re.search(r'\([^\)]+(\()', s)
print(match.group(1))
(
```

Then I try to make the substitution:

```
re.sub(match.group(1), r'\{', s)
```

but I get the following error:

```
error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 0
```

I really don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: What is the desired result if the string were `'(aaa) (bbb (ccc)) ddd'`? If it were `'(aaa (eee)) (bbb ccc) ddd'`?  If it were `'(aaa) (ee (ff (gg))) (bbb (ccc)) ddd'`?

Comment: "I really don't understand what's wrong." Did you try reading the documentation for `re.sub`? According to the documentation, what should the first argument be? The *regex pattern* to match and thus substitute, right? (After all, that's why we're using a `re` method for the substitution, not a built-in string method, right?) Do you see why the result of matching a pattern that looks for a `(`, might not be a valid regular expression in itself? (Hint: what would that result be?)

Comment: As an aside, Python's regexes cannot balance brackets, and thus cannot solve this problem in general. Of course we can hard-code to look for the second `(` and then everything from there until `)`, but this won't be "the innermost nested parentheses" in almost any other case.

Comment: @CarySwoveland desired results: for `'(aaa) (bbb (ccc)) ddd'` is `'(aaa) (bbb {ccc}) ddd'`; for `'(aaa (eee)) (bbb ccc) ddd'` is `'(aaa {eee}) (bbb ccc) ddd'`; for `'(aaa) (ee (ff (gg))) (bbb (ccc)) ddd'` is `'(aaa) (ee (ff {gg})) (bbb {ccc}) ddd'`

Comment: @KarlKnechtel what I didn't understand is that I used a regex in order to find the desired `(` in `match`, and so when I write `match.group(1)` I expected `re.sub` to use that regex. Now I guess `match.group(1)` doesn't contain the regex, but just the resulting string. But even in this case I expect `re.sub` to replace the first `(` with `{`. (It's super-difficult to me to understand documentations (for any language and tool, not just Python), I prefer to see a dozen examples in order to get how a thing works)

Comment: Honestly, this is a sign of just needing more practice, and paying more attention to trying to think logically.

Comment: @Karl, I agree with your comment #2 but a regular expression may still hold a prominent role in a solution to the problem. I have offered one that employs a regular expression that matches strings `'(...)'` that are *nested* to a specified level, varying the number of levels until a solution is found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
s = r'aaa (bbb (ccc)) ddd'
print( re.sub(r'\(([^()]*)\)', r'{\1}', s) )
# => aaa (bbb {ccc}) ddd
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/UFLCzD).

*Details*:

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `([^()]*)` - Group 1 (`\1`): any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.

The replacement is a Group 1 value wrapped with curly braces.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples and attempts, please try following code in Python, written and tested in Python3.x. Also here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/s4SMsQ/1) for used regex in code.

```
import re
var = r'aaa (bbb (ccc)) ddd'
print( re.sub(r'(^.*?\([^(]*)\(([^)]*)\)(.*)', r'\1{\2}\3', var) )
```

Output for shown samples, will be as follows:

```
aaa (bbb {ccc}) ddd
```

***Explanation of Python code:***

- Using python's `re` library here for regex.
- Creating a variable named `var` which has value `aaa (bbb (ccc)) ddd` in it.
- Then using `print` function of python3 to print value which we get from `re.sub` function which is performing substitution for us to get required output.

***Explanation of `re.sub` section:*** Basically we are using regex `(^.*?\([^(]*)\(([^)]*)\)(.*)`(explained below) which creates 3 capturing groups(only to get required values), where 1st capturing group captures value just before `(` which is present before `ccc` and 2nd capturing group has `ccc` in it and 3rd capturing group has rest of the value in it. While performing substitution we are simply substituting it with `\1{\2}\3` and wrapping value `ccc` within `{..}`

***Explanation of regex:***

```
(^.*?\([^(]*)  ##Creating 1st capturing group which matches values from starting of value to till first occurrence of ( 
               ##with a Lazy match followed by a match which matches anything just before next occurrence of (
\(             ##Matching literal ( here, NO capturing group here as we DO NOT want this in output.
([^)]*)        ##Creating 2nd capturing group which has everything just before next occurrence of ) in it.
\)             ##Matching literal ) here, NO capturing group here as we DO NOT want this in output.
(.*)           ##Creating 3rd capturing group which has rest values in it.
```

Answer (score 2):

You've gotten the argument order wrong:

> sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)

> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost
> non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern in string by the
> replacement repl.  repl can be either a string or a callable;
> if a string, backslash escapes in it are processed.  If it is
> a callable, it's passed the Match object and must return
> a replacement string to be used.

The pattern comes first, but because you've given it `match.group(1)`, it's seeing `'('` as the pattern, which contains unmatched and unescaped parentheses.

I think what you are after is something like:

```py
re.sub(r'\([^\)]+(\()', r'\1{', s)
'aaa ({ccc)) ddd'
```

Comment: "You've gotten the argument order wrong" seems like a strange way to describe the problem, given that `match.group(1)` (nor the result, `'('`) shouldn't be *any* of the arguments.

Comment: Note that it does not give the wanted output as requested by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

As indicated by your reply to my comment on the question, the following example strings are to be transformed as indicated:

```
'(aaa) (bbb (ccc)) ddd'                => '(aaa) (bbb {ccc}) ddd'
'(aaa (eee)) (bbb ccc) ddd'            => '(aaa {eee}) (bbb ccc) ddd'
'(aaa) (ee (ff (gg))) (bbb (ccc)) ddd' => '(aaa) (ee (ff {gg})) (bbb {ccc}) ddd'
```

We cannot obtain those results with a single regular expression but we can do so by executing a sequence of the regular expressions

```
r'\(([^()]*)\)(?=(?:[^()]*\)){n})'
```

for `n = 0, 1, ....` and substituting matches with

```
r'{\1}'
```

If `n = N` is the smallest value of `n` for which there is no match, the desired substitution is given by the string produced by `n = N-1`.

---

I have assumed the string has [balanced parentheses](https://www.baeldung.com/java-balanced-brackets-algorithm).

The strings `'a(b X c)'` and `'a(b(c(d X e)f)g)'` have balanced parentheses; `'a(b(c(d X e)fg)'` and `'a(b))cd X ((efg)'` do not.

The *nesting level* of any character in the string equals the number of right parentheses that follow before a left parenthesis is encountered (equivalently, the number of left parentheses that precede before a right parenthesis is encountered). The nesting levels of `'X'` in the following strings are as shown:

```
String          Nesting level
_____________________________
a X b                 0
a(b X c)              1
a(b(c X d)e)f         2
a(b(c(d X e)f)(g))    3
```

---

Consider the string

```
'(aaa) (ee (ff (gg))) (bbb (ccc)) ddd'
```

---

We first set `n = 0` to obtain

```
r'\(([^()]*)\)(?=(?:[^()]*\)){0})'
```

[Demo 0](https://regex101.com/r/h1aCZh/1) shows that the substitution of matches produces the string

```
{aaa} (ee (ff {gg})) (bbb {ccc}) ddd
```

---

Now set `n = 1` to produce the regular expression

```
\(([^()]*)\)(?=(?:[^()]*\)){1})
```

[Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/WlskaE/1) shows that the substitution of matches produces the string

```
(aaa) (ee (ff {gg})) (bbb {ccc}) ddd
```

---

Next set `n = 2` to produce the regular expression

```
\(([^()]*)\)(?=(?:[^()]*\)){2})
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/urMVsV/1) and [Python demo](https://tio.run/##JY3LCsIwEEX38xWzy4wUQd0JpR9iFPJq7MI2JCkopd8eR9zdA@dw06c@l/nS2vRKS66YA0CpGXtUZIxhpBCQxhEpRmZBay2Sc062914B5PgWOytNdHsQ3w@smYaehusfNfN23lnM8vPCsayWJOqk2fRpVx3KIQOkPM2VCkNrXw) show that the substitution of matches produces the string

```
(aaa) (ee (ff {gg})) (bbb (ccc)) ddd
```

---

Next set `n = 3` to produce the regular expression

```
\(([^()]*)\)(?=(?:[^()]*\)){3})
```

[Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/dnXY8H/1) shows that there are no matches. We  therefore conclude that `n = 2` is the greatest level of nested parentheses, so the desired substituted string must be that produced when `n = 2`:

```
(aaa) (ee (ff {gg})) (bbb (ccc)) ddd
```

[Demo 4](https://regex101.com/r/GTe0ww/1) illustrates that there may be ties.